# Condition "if" in mixin in Jade

Tags: pug, mixins

I am looking for the way to use "if" in mixin.

```
mixin fn(a)
    if a == "some"
        ...
    else
        ...

+fn("some")
```

Unfortunately, It doesn't work. And seems like "if" couldn't get the parameter "a". How could I deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some indentation problem in the code that you compiled. It works fine on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Amit-Kolambikar/pen/qbvREj). You can edit jade the jade to add more conditions.

```
mixin fn(name)
  if name == "amit"
    h2 Hello
  else
    h4 World

+fn("amit")
```

If you are using Arrays :

```
 mixin fn(a) 
 if a[0]== "a1"
    return var1
  else if a[1]== "a2"
    return var2

h2 #[+fn(["a21","a2"])]

h2 #[+fn(["a1","a2"])]
```

I have updated the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Amit-Kolambikar/pen/qbvREj) to cover arrays too. I have added a few more examples to cover different methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Finally I found that it works with a single variable , but not with a element in array.`if array[0] == "amit"` It doesn't work. And I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Check my edited answer and playaround with the CodePen. Try other combinations to understand it properly.

Comment: Finally I found out what's up.....It's really really a very very stupid mistake that I have never made for many years. I used a wrong index. Thanks again!

Comment: @奇真亦假 Happens to most. Could you mark my answer right then ? I am nearing 200 rep on stackoverflow Cheers!